# Фильтр для бота Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Допустим есть бот для модерации чата и фильтр ссылок и нежелательных слов благодаря которому удаляются сообщения :

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delete_links(message: types.Message):
    admins_list = [admin.user.id for admin in await bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=message.chat.id)]
    if message.from_user.id not in admins_list:
            
          if 'бля' in message.text:
            await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Однако в таком случае бот удаляет и подобные сообщения : "Нельзя оскор**бля**ть участников" т.к. видит ключевое слово.
Как можно исправить данную проблему, чтобы он не удалял сообщения подобного типа?

Comment: Pазбейте предложения на отдельные слова и проверяйте каждое слово

Comment: Можете поподробнее? Желательно с кодом

Comment: if if 'бля' in message.text.split(' '):

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает как надо

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def delete_links(message: types.Message):
    admins_list = [admin.user.id for admin in await bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id=message.chat.id)]
    if message.from_user.id not in admins_list:
           #С помощью split() мы разбиваем фразу на несколько строк отделяющиеся пробелам, тем самым выделяя(вырывая, проверяя) конкретное слово из контекста, а не из слова фразу. 
           if 'бля' in message.text.split(' '):
            await bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]